# MySQL - Stored Procedure Error

Tags: mysql

estoy escribiendo una Stored Procedure, y cuando ejecuto primero un SELECT llamando a una función, y luego intento crear un CURSOR, me aparece el error que se muestra a continuación

```
BEGIN
   
   DECLARE Sales DECIMAL(10,2);

   SELECT TotalEarnings(_FromDate, _ToDate) INTO Sales; 
 
    DECLARE CV CURSOR FOR 
       SELECT Sale_Id, SUM(Sale_Quantity * (Sale_Price - Sale_Cost)) AS Earn 
           FROM Sales_Details 
       WHERE Sales_Date BETWEEN _FromDate AND _ToDate;
```

Porque ocurre esto ? no se pueden juntar una función y un Cursor ?

```
Error de SQL (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE CV CURSOR FOR SELECT Sale_Id, SUM(Sale_Quantity * (Sale_Price - Sale_Cost)) AS Earn 
           FROM at line 17uery
```

Que puede estar mal ?

Gracias !

Comment: Elba, te encuentras en StackOverflow en español, por favor utiliza la opción editar para que puedas modificar tu pregunta por su equivalente en español. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo con la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html) de los cursores, no es posible hacer lo que muestras en el ejemplo.

> La declaracion del Cursor debe estar antes de la declaración del Handler y después de las declaraciones de variables y condiciones.

> *Cursor declarations **must** appear before handler declarations and after variable and condition declarations.*

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero ese no es el error.. adiciono el @ y sigue dando lo mismo

Comment: @ElbaNanero, el código que publicaste del Stored Procedure está completo o es solo una parte? La variable `Sales` la utilizas?

Comment: Si, claro, pero lo que quiero determinar, es porque si dejo la linea del SELECT comentariada, el error desaparece... y si la dejo. el cursor da error.

Comment: @ElbaNanero acabo de editar la respuesta porque según la documentación, no se puede

Comment: Esta es la respuesta correcta. Primero hay que hacer TODOSSSS los DECLARE y, después puede comenzar uno a hacer SELECT INTO variables.

Comment: Muchas Gracias !!! esa era la clave !! gracias

Comment: @ElbaNanero si te parece que mi respuesta era lo que buscabas, por favor márcala como aceptada,

Comment: Si me indicas como hacerlo lo hago

Comment: En el lado izquierdo de la respuesta encontrarás un ícono de check mark, puedes hacerle click  para marcar la respuesta como aceptada. [ver más](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%c3%b3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%c3%b3n-de-respuestas/428#428). Fue un gusto poder hacer un aporte.